# How do I create a year dummy variable from two date variables as a range in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-range

I have the following data format:

```
name     role       startdate      enddate
abby     associate  2/15/2010      6/13/2012
bobby    intern     6/21/2013      1/10/2014
james    manager    2/12/2012      5/13/2015
```

I want to create a year dummy variable for the startdate and enddate range (e.g. 2010=1 if the startdate and enddate is within 1/1/2010 - 12/31/2010 range, so that it will generate the following output:

```
name     role       startdate      enddate     2010    2011    2012
abby     associate  2/15/2010      6/13/2012    1       1       1
bobby    intern     6/21/2013      1/10/2014    0       0       0
james    manager    2/12/2012      5/13/2015    0       0       1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: how is your data stored? is it a dataframe? then when you say dummy variables you mean columns in a dataframe?

Comment: Why are there no columns for 2013, 2014, 2015?

Comment: it is a pandas dataframe. and yes, the dummy variables are stored in columns

Comment: "2010=1 if the startdate and enddate is within 1/1/2010 - 12/31/2010" but in your example enddate is not within given range and the value is still 1. Which one is correct?

Comment: I think he mentions that if startdata is in the year 2010 and enddate in year 2012 then columns 2010, 2011 and 2012 should be 1. I'm not sure what role do days and months play here. This will end with a lot of columns simulating a sparse matrix. @lindws why do you want that? is it to have a filter by dates precomputed? why not computing it on the fly? and if the dataframe is too big to compute that everytime why not storing this in an efficient way? Or are you planing to export this in excel to be user friendly?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki what do you mean by computing it on the fly and storing it in an efficient way?

Comment: It means that instead of storing all this columns you create a function where you pass a year and it will return 1 or 0, making the computations when you call the function instead of storing all this info in tens of different columns

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki can you share how you would do that? I still need the year column though but I have been getting errors when I tried to compare the dates

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement function from scratch

```
# Change to pandas datetime type
df[['startdate','enddate']] = df[['startdate','enddate']].apply(pd.to_datetime, infer_datetime_format=True)
# take years from date columns
df['startdate_year'] =pd.DatetimeIndex(df['startdate']).year
df['enddate_year'] =pd.DatetimeIndex(df['enddate']).year

## min and max values of column
min = df['startdate_year'].min()
max =df['enddate_year'].max()

# creating dictionary  
year_dict = {k: [] for v, k in enumerate([i for i in range(min,max+1)])}
#{2010: [], 2011: [], 2012: [], 2013: [], 2014: [], 2015: []}

def getdummi(start,end):
    values = [i for i in range(start,end+1)]
    return [1 if i in values else 0 for i in year_dict.keys()]
# getdummi(2012,2014) 
#[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

data = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    data.append(getdummi(row['startdate_year'],row['enddate_year']))

dfdummi =pd.DataFrame(data,columns=list(year_dict.keys()))
dfdummi
```

[image]

Then concat result in pandas

```
df = pd.concat([df,dfdummi],axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

creating dummy dataframe with just start and end year

```
 df_test = pd.DataFrame([[2012,2014],[2015,2017],[2010, 2020]], columns= ['start_date', 'end_date'])

 #make sure to convert year column to numerical value , and use pandas loc function to assign new column with value 1

 for current_col in range(min_year, max_year+1):
     df_test.loc[(df_test['start_date']<=current_col) & (df_test['end_date']>=current_col), current_col] = 1
```

fill blank value with zero

```
  df_test = df_test.fillna(0)
```

you will get the desired output